# Как удалить из текста повторяющиеся значения, соответствующие регулярному выражению python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пример:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec et odio. 
Arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam.
//iseuhskdj.xrv_800
//iseuhskdj.xrv_800
//iseuhskdj.xrv_800 
Nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna nunc id. 
Platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada. Faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit amet.
-Picture-
-Picture-
```

В данном случае нужно оставить только одно `//iseuhskdj.xrv_800` и только одно `-Picture-`.

При этом убрать все повторяющиеся значения нельзя, т.к. в тексте могут повторяться слова

Есть какие-то простые решения для подобной задачи?

Comment: А добавьте в вопрос как в коде вы вытаскиваете регуляркой из того текста. Есть идея, но нужно знать как регулярка используется :)

Answer (score 2):

```
text = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec et odio. 
Arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam.
//iseuhskdj.xrv_800
//iseuhskdj.xrv_800
//iseuhskdj.xrv_800
Nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna nunc id. 
Platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada. Faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit amet.
-Picture-
-Picture-"""

rows = text.split("\n")
previous = None
new_rows = []
for row in rows:
    if row != previous:
        new_rows.append(row)
        previous = row

result =  "\n".join(new_rows)
print(result)
```

---

*Вывод:*

> ```
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec et odio. 
> Arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam.
> //iseuhskdj.xrv_800
> Nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna nunc id. 
> Platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada. Faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit amet.
> -Picture-
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, вам надо убрать повторяющиеся подряд строки. Создаёте `a = set()` и проверяете, есть ли очередная строка в `a`. Если да, то переходите к следующей, иначе выводите на экран и сохраняете в `a`.